# Create a job in Parse which delete all old objects in all Classes

Tags: class, parse-platform, chat

I have created a chat app in IOS with Parse.com. I want after 30min to delete all old messages. Every chatroom is a class in parse which contains the messages between two users.

Can you help me to create a repeatly job in parse that search for old messages in all classes and deletes them ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid exceeding the request limit, maybe you should delete the objects in every single minute. You can find out all the objects and delete them by something like this.

```
var time = new Date(new Date() - 30*60*1000);        // 30min ago
var query = new Parse.Query('ChatLog');
query.lessThan('createdAt', time);
query.limit(1000);
query.find().then(function(results) {
    return Parse.Object.destroyAll(results);
});
```

Comment: "ChatLog" is the name of class? Sorry but i am new with parse

Comment: Repeat for every classes. You can't enumerate all classes on Parse programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

The answer from @iForests is good. There is likely a way to do this same thing with `.each()` which won't have any query limits. Maybe something like:

```
var thirtyMinutes = 30*60*1000
var now = new Date()
var thirtyMinutesAgo = new Date(now-thirtyMinutes)

var query = new Parse.Query('ChatLog')
query.lessThan('createdAt', thirtyMinutesAgo)

var objectsToDelete = []

query.each(function(object){
  objectsToDelete.push(object)
}).then(function(){
  var howManyDeleted = objectsToDelete.length
  Parse.Object.destroyAll(objectsToDelete)
  status.success(howManyDeleted+' chat logs deleted.')
}, function(error){
  status.error('Error during background job.')
})
```

Forgive my lack of semi-colons--I'm a Swift person :) Good luck!

Comment: In my experience, when you use destroyAll() to delete 100 objects, the request count still +100.